# How to interpret diffrent XML documents?

Tags: xml, logging

I have a webservice(.net) that will fetch(AfterReceiveRequest) the incoming message and then check the header for client identifications.

When logging the data with the built-in log I get e document like this :

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
<System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
<EventID>0</EventID>
<Type>3</Type>
<SubType Name="Information">0</SubType>
<Level>8</Level>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-11-03T14:58:51.4037710Z" />
<Source Name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" />
<Correlation ActivityID="{cca863d4-c100-4890-bdee-b2822b8c3c51}" />
<Execution ProcessName="w3wp" ProcessID="1668" ThreadID="11" />
<Channel />
<Computer>MYComputer</Computer>
</System>
<ApplicationData>
<TraceData>
<DataItem>
<MessageLogTraceRecord Time="2011-11-03T15:58:51.4027703+01:00" Source="ServiceLevelReceiveRequest" Type="System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessage" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/ServiceModel/Management/MessageTrace">
<HttpRequest>
<Method>POST</Method>
<QueryString></QueryString>
<WebHeaders>
<Connection>Keep-Alive</Connection>
<Content-Length>411</Content-Length>
<Content-Type>text/xml; charset=utf-8</Content-Type>
<Accept-Encoding>gzip, deflate</Accept-Encoding>
<Expect>100-continue</Expect>
<Host>localhost</Host>
<VsDebuggerCausalityData>uIDPo+iMUXXYvrRMsLtwZXbu2nsAAAAA9T4PAazUO0qPWWgM4JKb9L8HlsY5ehRBsbM2cjOrd2YACQAA</VsDebuggerCausalityData>
<SOAPAction>"GetVersion"</SOAPAction>
</WebHeaders>
</HttpRequest>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Header>
<SecurityToken xmlns="ns" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Password xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyApp.DataContracts.External">MyPassword</Password>
<UserName xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ MyApp.DataContracts.External">MyUserName</UserName>
</SecurityToken>
<To s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://MyApp.local/Test/Integration.svc</To>
<Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">GetVersion</Action>
</s:Header>
</s:Envelope>
</MessageLogTraceRecord>
</DataItem>
</TraceData>
</ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
```

Now I need to convert this to a regular XML message that I can send in forexample soapUI.

When adding a project in soupUI I get the following

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body/>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I need to add the header information here but are not sure how this would look like. I have tried to copy parts from the log into the XML message but this does nothing.

1. How do I translate the log header to the SoupUI header?
2. Why does this not the same as regular XML like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/)? What does soapenv:Envelope comes from? And why is the raw xml in the log loock different?

Comment: How exactly is this not "regular XML"? Are you confused by the use of namespace prefixes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By experimenting I got the following :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header>
     <SecurityToken xmlns="ns" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
       <Password xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyApp.DataContracts.External">MyUser</Password>
       <UserName xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyApp.DataContracts.External">MyPassword</UserName>
     </SecurityToken>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body/>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This works great!

Im however not clear why the log have  while the soupUI have ?